# Does it make sense to recompute Parks-Mccellan on a per sample basis?

Tags: real-time, parks-mclellan

I'm thinking of using Parks-Mccellan for my equalization needs, but since I require that the filter be variable (gain, Q etc.) then does it make sense to recompute Parks-Mccellan on a **per sample** basis?

Reason for asking is that I'm still confused about whether different algorithms are suited for per sample computation or whether they need longer intervals to make their full effect.

I guess it would still need some sort of pre-buffer (since the filtering uses previous samples)?

---

My application is Parks-Mccellan style arbitrary magnitude response filtering that's dynamic (i.e. I want to be able to vary the magnitude response over some, even short sample intervals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Parks-McClellan algorithm, which is based on the [Remez exchange algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm), is a computationally quite expensive iterative method that is most commonly used for off-line filter designs. It is not at all well-suited for real-time applications, let alone for re-designing a filter each sample interval.

Depending on your application, you might be looking for an adaptive filter based on the [LMS (least mean squares) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter).

Another approach, again dependent on the application, is to use an appropriate parametrization of the filter, where the parameters could be the gain, center frequency, Q factor, etc. This is easily possible with second order IIR filters.

Comment: So you think LMS is substantially more suited for real-time application than PM? LMS seems fairly similar to PM in terms of parameters.

Comment: @mavavilj: Yes, LMS *is* a real-time algorithm, whereas PM isn't. I'm not sure why you think they are "similar in terms of parameters". I wouldn't say so.

Comment: They both allow to define an arbitrary magnitude response with "don't care regions". http://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firls.html

Comment: @mavavilj: We're talking about different methods. A least squares method (firls) is different from an adaptive algorithm such as LMS, which is also implemented in Matlab: [dsp.LMSFilter](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.lmsfilter-class.html).

Comment: what are the *"don't care regions"* with respect to LMS adaptive filters?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The OP referred to `firls`, i.e., to a least squares design method with filter specs similar to Parks McClellan, not the LMS adaptive filter algorithm.

Comment: i guess i didn't notice that reference.  and yes MATLAB's `firls()` is sorta interchangeable with `firpm()`, but gives different results (actually measures error with two different norms).  not sure how i would relate `firls()` to the LMS.  maybe they might have similar results if the error weighting function supplied to `firls()` is flat and the LMS was allowed to settle down (and the LTI system the LMS was adapting to was the same target supplied to `firls()`.