# "Desired signal" in LMS adaptive filters?

Tags: adaptive-filters

I'm trying to understand how to specify the "desired signal" in adaptive LMS filters such as the following: [This one](http://www.mrtc.mdh.se/projects/wcet/wcet_bench/lms/lms.c), or [this one](http://read.pudn.com/downloads158/ebook/707037/10%20DSP%20applications%20using%20C%20and%20the%20TMS320C6X%20DSK/Chp07.pdf) page 7, or [this one](http://gplib.sourceforge.net/classgplib_1_1LMSCanceller.html#a6398f704207d3184f5548a23a728dda7).

- It seems like the example there uses it for noise suppression?
- But why is the desired signal input + noise?
- Isn't it what we want to get rid of, rather than desire?

I'm trying to use LMS for "arbitrary magnitude response" filtering (as suggested [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/31887/16003)).

Comment: I think you need to describe your application in more detail. From your previous questions it sounds like you want a filter with a (totally?) different magnitude response at each new incoming sample. This doesn't make much sense to me. Where do these quickly changing magnitude specs come from?

Comment: @MattL. Well that's close. I'm wanting to do an equalizer to which I compute magnitude responses from FFT analysis. So I can get data, but I don't know how to shape a filter to that data. And yes, it should vary even on a per sample basis (since you need to compute the envelopes adjusting from one FFT analysis frame to another).